# Add Subscriber into Auto Suppression List Using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, autosuppressionlist

I'm trying to add the subscribers from normal Data extension to 'Auto Suppression List' using the SSJS but my code below code is not working in case of auto suppression list it wokrs with normal Data extension,

With list function:

```
var myList = List.Init("Auto-Suppression-list-Test");
myList.Subscribers.Add("test@gmail.com",{DateAdded:"Oct 8 2019 1:41AM"});
```

With DE function:

```
var de = DataExtension.Init("Auto-Suppression-list-Test") 
var arrContacts =  [{Email Address: "test@gmail.com" ,Date Added:"Oct 8 2019 1:41AM"}];
var status = de.Rows.Add(arrContacts);
```

Auto Suppression List is DE or list?
Am I doing something wrong/missed anything in the code?

Comment: an Auto-suppression list is a DE and not a list

Comment: Hi @EazyE, thank you so much for your response. Yes, I went through that question, It's more about deleting the subscriber from the auto suppression list. Sorry, I'm new to the SSJS. Could you help to get the syntax of Platform Function to add the subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auto-Suppression list, despite its name, is a Data Extension.

Here's how to insert a row to an Auto-Suppression list:

```js
<script runat="server">
var addRow = Platform.Function.InsertData('Auto-supression list name',['Email Address'],['sample@example.com']);
</script>
```

You will have to add a [loop](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/29/loops-in-ampscript-and-server-side-javascript/) to insert more contacts in one go. You don't need to pass `DateAdded`, it will be populated automatically.